# Using Laravel to build e-commerce web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I'm using Laravel to build an e-commerce web app, but I'm actually can't activate a modal that properly works on the HTML template when trying to delete an item. It's just not showing the modal. I've tried to follow some tutorials about this issue but still do not have the expected result, so I guess the problem is in the code.

```
<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title">All categories</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-header -->
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div id="example1_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper dt-bootstrap4">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="dataTables_length" id="example1_length"><label>Show <select
                                                    name="example1_length" aria-controls="example1"
                                                    class="custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm">
                                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                                <option value="25">25</option>
                                                <option value="50">50</option>
                                                <option value="100">100</option>
                                            </select> entries</label></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                                    <div id="example1_filter" class="dataTables_filter"><label>Search:<input
                                                    type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder=""
                                                    aria-controls="example1"></label></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable dtr-inline"
                                           role="grid" aria-describedby="example1_info">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr role="row">
                                            <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1"
                                                colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending"
                                                aria-label="Num.: activate to sort column descending">Num.
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1"
                                                colspan="1"
                                                aria-label="Category Name: activate to sort column ascending">Category
                                                Name
                                            </th>
                                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1"
                                                colspan="1" aria-label="Actions: activate to sort column ascending">
                                                Actions
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        @foreach ($categories as $category)
                                            <tr role="row" class="odd">
                                                <td class="sorting_1 dtr-control">{{$increment}}</td>
                                                <td>{{$category->nom_categorie}}</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="{{url('/editcategory'.$category->id)}}"
                                                       class="btn btn-primary"><i class="nav-icon fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                                                    <a href="{{url('/deletecategory'.$category->id)}}" id="delete"
                                                       class="btn btn-danger"><i class="nav-icon fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            {{$increment = $increment + 1}}
                                        @endforeach

                                        </tbody>
                                        <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Num.</th>
                                            <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Category Name</th>
                                            <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Actions</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </tfoot>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
                                    <div class="dataTables_info" id="example1_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">
                                        Showing 1 to 2 of 2 entries
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
                                    <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="example1_paginate">
                                        <ul class="pagination">
                                            <li class="paginate_button page-item previous disabled"
                                                id="example1_previous"><a href="#" aria-controls="example1"
                                                                          data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0"
                                                                          class="page-link">Previous</a></li>
                                            <li class="paginate_button page-item active"><a href="#"
                                                                                            aria-controls="example1"
                                                                                            data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0"
                                                                                            class="page-link">1</a></li>
                                            <li class="paginate_button page-item next disabled" id="example1_next"><a
                                                        href="#" aria-controls="example1" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0"
                                                        class="page-link">Next</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-body -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.card -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</section>
<!-- /.content -->
```

Comment: Are you sure that the css and javascript for that `modal` already imported properly? Are you sure that there's already the javascript that manage the show/hide and behavior of modal?

Comment: @DhanaD. Yes i've added the javascript after the code i previously post
I tried to post the script but it's not going